# GL drawing view clears drawings on rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, drawing

I am making a simple drawing app - I have modified the apple GLPaint example somewhat. The problem is when the user rotates the device, the drawings are cleared. is there a way around this?

I'm also having trouble saving an image representation, if you know about this take a look:
[Saving imageRef from GLPaint creates completely black image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857912/saving-imageref-from-glpaint-creates-completely-black-image)

Answer (score 0):

I determined that this was due to layoutSubviews being called which was destroying then creating the frameBuffer. I created a bool that tracked if the frame buffer had been created once and then only destroyed/created the first time. the view was loaded.